# Import deleted Items from Intuit QuickBooks?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have integrated intuit quick books in my current application. I am using V3 version of quick books api with my ASP.NET application. I want to import all deleted items from quick books not inactive. only permanently deleted items. I have already imported inactive items.

Please let me know is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Change Data Capture" feature of the API for this:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/020_key_concepts/00600_changedata_operation

Poll Intuit's API with a query like this periodically:

- https://quickbooks.api.intuit.com/v3/company/1234/cdc?entities=Item&changedSince=2012-07-20T22:25:51-07:00

And you'll get back XML/JSON that has a `status=` attribute that will be set to `deleted` if the item is deleted.

Comment: thanks for reply. I have tried the solution you gave and i got the response in XML, but in that XML i am not getting any field says status

Comment: Post the XML you're getting back so we can see what you're seeing.